# How to increase request header size in Spring WebFlux with Netty?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, netty

Is there a way to configure **maximum http request header size** for a request in **Spring WebFlux** with embedded **Netty** server?

I am getting following exception.

> io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$HeaderListSizeException:
> Header size exceeded max allowed size (8192)

I tried to use this property `server.max-http-header-size` but it didn't work.

Comment: You have to put something like this `server.max-http-header-size=10KB`

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: Are we talking about server method handler or calling another service by WebClient?

Comment: So I am calling my api from frontend when I send jwt token in request header from frontend then at backend I get this exception Header size exceeded max allowed size (8192)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by upgrading the Spring Boot version from 2.3.12.RELEASE to 2.7.0 and the Spring Cloud version from Hoxton.SR9 to 2021.0.3, following the compatibility matrix provided by Spring Cloud and Spring Boot.

Additionally, I implemented the WebServerFactoryCustomizer interface and overridden customize method in which I wrote the logic to increase the header size. Here's the code snippet I used to achieve this

```
@Component
public class CustomizeNetty implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer -> httpServer.http2Settings(builder -> builder.maxHeaderListSize(65536)));
    }
}
```